# Missing php-redis repository in docker debian stretch image

Tags: php, docker, redis, debian-stretch

I'm missing the repository that includes the `php-redis` package. Inside my debian 9/stretch docker container I run the following:

```
root@dcc82d674095 [19:36:46] [/var/www/html]
-> # apt-get install php-redis
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package php-redis is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'php-redis' has no installation candidate
```

However if I run `apt search php-redis` I can see that it is "there":

```
root@dcc82d674095 [19:41:18] [/var/www/html]
-> # apt search php-redis
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
php-redis/stable,stable 3.1.1-1 amd64
  (none)
```

My `/etc/apt/sources.list` looks like this:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main
```

My *guess* is that I'm missing a resource in that `sources.list` file. What repo am I missing? I'd also like to know how I find where the source is from so a similar situation happens again I can figure it out rather than asking another question.

I looked at this page - but couldn't figure out any link that looked like I should add it to my `sources.list` file. (That's just my assumption of what is going wrong).

https://packages.debian.org/source/stretch/php-redis

---

#### EDIT:

While I am still interested in finding an answer to my question, I found a work around by installing the package through pecl. In my docker file I added the following:

```
# printf statement mocks answering the prompts from the pecl install
RUN printf "\n \n" | pecl install redis && docker-php-ext-enable redis
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use php:7.1-fpm-stretch container, all php-*** packages are blocked for installation, see detail here: https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/713

This leads to the following documentation in their github repository:

- https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/php#e-package-php-xxx-has-no-installation-candidate

Which explains the following:

> The proper solution to this error is to either use FROM debian:XXX and install Debian's PHP packages directly, or to use docker-php-ext-install, pecl, and/or phpize to install the necessary additional extensions and utilities.